# Tmux: How can I use the identifiers in the paste buffer list to paste a specific buffer?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, tmux

I use the `C-b =` command in Tmux to select a specific paste buffer from a list.

I wonder how I can use the identifiers `(0),...,(9)` and `(M-a),...,(M-z)` to directly paste specified buffer? Indeed, `C-b ]` paste the `(0)` buffer.

Furthermore, is it possible to paste a buffer using its name, e.g. "buffer69"?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit in brackets is the key to press, so you can paste buffer 42 by pressing `C-b = M-r`.

Alternatively you can use the command prompt: `C-b : pasteb -b buffer42`.

It is possible to bind a key to make a command prompt that just asks for the buffer name, something like:

```
bind B command-prompt -pbuffer 'pasteb -b "%%"'
```

Comment: Thank you. Small errata: *the bit in **parentheses***. Also `M-z` is two keys? :)

Comment: Parentheses are also called brackets. M-z is Meta and z together, usually Alt-z on modern keyboards.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but is `M-z` considered a single key, just like `^-C` (Control-C)?

Comment: Yes it is a single key like C-c, you press Meta and z together for M-z same as you press Ctrl and c together for C-c.